# UART serial communication between STM32 MCUs

Tags: stm32, uart

Good day everyone I am new to the group.  I would like to ask for your hints regarding the UART communication between 2 STM32 MCUs.
Basically I have 2 STM32 MCUs connected through UART.  A button on MCU1 will trigger an output on MCU2 and vice versa.  Initially I tried a single button from MCU1 which drives a single output in MCU2 and this is OK.  However when I added another button2 to MCU1 I could no longer transmit data from Button2 to MCU2.
Here's my code for the Transmit MCU1:

```
USART2 -> CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;  
USART2 -> CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE;  
USART2 -> CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE;  
USART2 -> CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;  
USART2 -> CR1 |= USART_CR1_TXEIE;      
NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
.
.
.

void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{    
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);

//this is the first transmit code for button1 which is successfully transmitted to MCU2

if(USART2 -> SR & USART_SR_TXE)    
{    
    {    
        if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BUTTON1_GPIO_Port, BUTTON1_Pin))    
        {
                      //transmit this data to MCU2                
                      USART2 -> DR = 0xFF;                                                                                    
        }    
        else     
        {    
              //transmit this data to MCU2    
                     USART2 -> DR = 0x00;                                    
        }
    }
}

//this is the second transmit code for button2 but this never gets transmitted to MCU2    
    
if(USART2 -> SR & USART_SR_TXE)
{
    {
        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BUTTON2_GPIO_Port, BUTTON2_Pin))
        {
             //transmit this data to MCU2
                       USART2 -> DR = 0xF0;                            
        }
        else            
        {
             //transmit this data to MCU2
                       USART2 -> DR = 0x0F;                            
        }
    }
}
    
//this is the first receive code from MCU2 and successfully transmitted to MCU1    

if(USART2 -> SR & USART_SR_RXNE)        
{    
    {
        if(USART2 -> DR == 0xE3)
        {
            //enable output

                        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }
        else if(USART2 -> DR == 0x1C)
        {
            //disable output

                       HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }        
    }
}
        
//this is the second receive code from MCU2 but unsuccessfully transmitted to MCU1    

if(USART2 -> SR & USART_SR_RXNE)
{
    {    
        if(USART2->DR == 0xCC)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED2_GPIO_Port, LED2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }
        else if(USART2->DR == 0x33)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED2_GPIO_Port, LED2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: You must not read the data register multiple times, the read has side effects, you must read into a variable and conduct comparisons against that.   But this is likely only the start of what is wrong with this code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for the hint.  You mean I need to declare a single variable and compare it against all data.  Do I have to consolidate all TX data (0xFF, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x0F) in a single loop?  And the same will be for the RX data (0xE3, 0x1C, 0xCC, 0x33)?

Comment: You must only read the data register once per received character.  What you do next is up to you.

Comment: Read `USART2->DR` into a variable at the start of your `USART2_IRQHandler` and then use that variable to compare against.

Comment: @brhans  I did this way but somehow it's not ok.  I used variable dr.
HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);

if(USART2 -> SR & USART_SR_TXE)    
{    
  uint8_t dr = USART2 -> DR;  
  if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BUTTON1_GPIO_Port, BUTTON1_Pin))    
  {  dr = 0xFF;                                                                                    
  }    
  else     
  { dr = 0x00;                                    
  }
  if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BUTTON2_GPIO_Port, BUTTON2_Pin))
  { dr = 0xF0;                            
  }
   else            
  { dr = 0x0F;                            
  }
}

Comment: I said to *read* `USART2->DR` into a variable and use that variable to *compare against*, not to write to the variable.
Writing into the variable doesn't have any effect on the UART. If you want the UART to send data, then you have to write to `USART2->DR`.
I was referring to the receive part of your interrupt handler inside the `if(USART2 -> SR & USART_SR_RXNE) `.

Comment: @brhans thanks now its working fine.  I realized that I cannot transmit and receive multiple data using a single IRQHandler.  If it is single transmit and receive it works fine in the IRQhandler. A multiple data is having problem.